# CasperJs loads json data from a local file

Tags: json, file, load, casperjs

Is there any convenient way to load a local JSON file into a variable with CasperJs?

I saw someone suggest to use

```
$.getJSON(filename, function() ...
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have the following working on CasperJS 1.1-beta1 and PhantomJS 1.9.1

test.json

```
{
    "test": "hello"
}
```

test.js

```
var json = require('test.json');
require('utils').dump(json);
casper.echo(json.test); // "hello"
```

Comment: What about if the file is on a remote server? For example: `http://mysite.tld/test.json`. It's seems that `require` can't do that... :(

Answer (score 6):

The solution proposed by @hexid worked for me with one change, i added a './' before the file address to denote it is a local file.

test.json

```
{
    "test": "hello"
}
```

test.js

```
var utils = require('utils');
var json = require('./test.json');

utils.dump(json);
utils.dump(json.test); // hello
utils.dump(json["test"]); // hello
```

(i would add it as a comment but I'd need 50+ rep to do that)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a complete sample

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

var json = require('test.json');
require('utils').dump(json);
casper.echo(json['test']);

casper.exit();
```